# Wicket AjaxLink erases onclick listeners

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, wicket

In our project we have an AjaxLink:

```
<a title="some title.." wicket:id="addMessage">Add</a>
```

Incide Page.class:

```
add(new AjaxLink() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //...
    }
    @Override 
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new AjaxCallListener() {
            @Override 
            public CharSequence getPrecondition(Component component) {
                return "return isPropagationAllowed()";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(Adding `AjaxCallListener` with method `getPrecondition()` stops `onclick()` method from being executed on some conditions (it should return a name of a function from your js which returns boolean))

Then I define a listener for that html element by js (+ JQuery) and put some behaviour to that:

```
$('[title]').each((i, elem) => elem.onclick = (event) => {
    /* ..manually open a tooltip.... */
})
```

It works as intended until that AjaxLink executes. Then my onclick listener dissapears for some reason, and then to make it work I should bind it manually.

Do you have any idea why is this (the erasure of other listeners) happening and how to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that the link has been re-created in the DOM due to some `target.add(ajaxLinkOrParent)` call on the server side. The old one with the `onclick` attribute is removed and a new one is created.

You should use jQuery "live" binding instead, e.g. `$(document).on('click', '[title]', function(evt) {showTooltip();})`